# Wordpress - All post titles in the post management page in admin are same as first in the page

Tags: wordpress

All post titles in the post management page in admin are same as first in the page.
Though upon clicking it leads to the correct post to edit, and the blog runs fine.
Seems like a small bug. I doubt updating jetpack has caused this since that's the only change I did in the last few days.
Noticed the first post title of every page in post mngmnt admin is repeated.
Please help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: deactivate all plugins and using the default WP theme to do the test and then activate the plugin one by one to see if there are something goes wrong.

Comment: Have done that already. I suspect jetpack caused the damage. however deactivating jetpack did not help.

Comment: Just replaced each and every file of wp-admin. Did not help. Using WP 4.6.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing the same version again helped. All okay.
Thanks to all who cared.